# Use previous row value for calculating log

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

I have a Dataframe as presented in the Spreadsheet, It has a column **A**.

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1h3ED1FbkxQxyci0ETQio8V4cqaAOC7bIJ5NvVx41jA/edit?usp=sharing

I have been trying to create a new column like **A_output** which uses the previous row value and current row value for finding the Natual Log.

```
df.apply(custom_function, axix=1) #on a function
```

But I am not sure, How to access the previous value of the row?

The only thing I have tried is converting the values into the list and perform my operation and appending it back to the dataframe something like this.

```
output = []
previous_value = 100
for value in df['A'].values:
    output.append(np.log(value/previous_value))
    previous_value = value

df['A_output'] = output
```

This is going to be extremely expensive operation, What's the best way to approach this problem?

Comment: I think you want `df['A_output'] = np.log(df['A'] / df['A'].shift(-1))`?

Comment: Where are we defining using the base value 100 ?

Comment: See answer for solution

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Another way with `rolling()`:

```py
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

data = np.random.normal(loc=5., size=(6, 1))
df = pd.DataFrame(columns=['A'], data=data)

df['output'] = df['A'].rolling(2).apply(lambda x: np.log(x[1]/x[0]))
init_val = 3.
df['output'][0] = np.log(df['A'][0] / init_val) # <-- manually assign value for the first item
print(df)
#           A    output
# 0  7.257160  0.883376
# 1  4.579390 -0.460423
# 2  4.630148  0.011023
# 3  5.153198  0.107029
# 4  6.004917  0.152961
# 5  6.633857  0.099608
```

If you want to apply the same operation on multiple columns:

```py
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

data = np.random.normal(loc=5., size=(6, 2))
df = pd.DataFrame(columns=['A', 'B'], data=data)

df[['output_A', 'output_B']] = df.rolling(2).apply(lambda x: np.log(x[1]/x[0]))
init_val = 3.
df['output_A'][0] = np.log(df['A'][0] / init_val)
df['output_B'][0] = np.log(df['B'][0] / init_val)
print(df)
#           A         B  output_A  output_B
# 0  7.289657  4.986245  0.887844  0.508071
# 1  5.690721  5.010605 -0.247620  0.004874
# 2  5.773812  5.129814  0.014495  0.023513
# 3  4.417981  6.395500 -0.267650  0.220525
# 4  4.923170  5.363723  0.108270 -0.175936
# 5  5.279008  5.327365  0.069786 -0.006802
```

Comment: Thanks, This is really good. For larger dataset is this going to be effective? Right ?

Comment: Great, glad it helped. Consider accepting my answer.

Comment: I think this is the fastest option there is.

Comment: Sure, one more questions! How would I use two columns previous value?

Comment: Updated my answer to apply this operation on multiple columns

Answer (score 0):

We can use `Series.shift` and after use `.loc` to assign the first value with the base value

Let's assume we have the following dataframe:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'A':np.random.randint(1, 10, 5)})

print(df)
   A
0  8
1  3
2  3
3  1
4  5
```

---

```
df['A_output'] = np.log(df['A'] / df['A'].shift())

df.loc[0, 'A_output'] = np.log(df.loc[0, 'A'] / 100)

print(df)
   A  A_output
0  8 -2.525729
1  3 -0.980829
2  3  0.000000
3  1 -1.098612
4  5  1.609438
```